# How do I overwrite the contents of the repository with my working copy in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: tortoisesvn

Lets say, I know there is going to be a conflict with me committing but  I don't want to deal with merging or anything.

I simply want to overwrite the repositories version with my own.  What is the tortoisesvn command to do so?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. First you have to make an update (SVN Update), so the conflict is actually happening.
2. Then you get three files in your directory: *yourfilename*.mine *yourfilename*.rX *yourfilename*.rY (X and Y are the original and the new revision numbers)
3. Rename the .mine file to the original file name.
4. Mark the conflicted file as resolved. (TortoiseSVN -> Resolved) (The .r? files will be deleted automatically)
5. After that you can commit the file as it were a normal change. (SVN Commit)

Comment: You need to be careful here that the working copy version is right when you mark it "resolved"--otherwise, your repository may be full of the "===" diff markers.

Answer (score 6):

Look at the [`svn resolve`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.resolve.html) command from the [red book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/).  With a command line client, you would be able to run

```
svn update
svn resolve -R --accept mine-full
```

It doesn't appear that TortoiseSVN makes this available, but if you have the command line client as backup, it may be handy.  Otherwise, I'd go with a hack of the sort Neil describes (move working copy files, update, replace working copy files).

A big caution: Using the [`Resolved...`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.resolved.html) command instead will accept the conflict-containing version after the update; you really want the file before the update.

Answer (score 1):

Another (horrible) possibility:

- Check out the version you know you are going to conflict with into a separate directory from your own stuff
- Copy your working files over the ones in the separate directory - take care not to copy the .svn files
- Commit from the separate directory